# Can I use shortage instead of "material in short supply"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "shortage" instead of "material in short supply". 
For example, "The other two shortages will be pulled in next Monday", I mean the other two items in short supply now will arrive next Monday.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more context? As of now, your sentence looks incomplete. When you use "shortage", it isn't clear what is in shortage.

Comment: I have not come across the expression **pulled in** in that context although I've seen frequent reference to **making up** a shortage.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "shortage" you are depending on the context to clarify what you mean. 
Generally a shortage is a lack of something, not the thing that is lacking. Since there is a simple alternative "items in short supply", I would use that alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have other way of indicating the thing lacking?